# What design pattern is simple inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I've recently read some concepts in OOP (yes, I'm a noob) and one of the concepts I read is Design Patterns. I've checked most of the patterns and a question struck me:

What's the name or term of such pattern that would simply inherit/extend an abstract class or any class to such matter? Or is it not even a design pattern?

e.g. Abstract Class Drink, Class Juice extends Drink, Class Soda extends Drink etc.

Comment: That would be simply ["inheritance"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html). It's not a design pattern.

Comment: In a list of architectural styles (Gothic, Baroque, Neoclassical, Postmodern), what would be the term for a window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have said, inheritance is not a design pattern: it is just inheritance.

Are you actually asking whether there is a design pattern that uses just a single class hierarchy, using just inheritance and not composition? There is such a design pattern: the Template Method pattern.

Comment: Oh well, Thank you Raedwald for answering my question and informing me of the existence of Template Method Pattern. I appreciate all answers :D

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is not a design pattern. Inheritance is one of the way to making design pattern. if you can understand Decorator pattern, You will be able to understand that why we use inheritance in java OOP. How about check this website :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Oh well, Thank you Jae Yeoul Ahn for answering my question. I appreciate all answers :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pattern, it's just *Inheritance*, as stated in the Java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html).

Comment: Oh well, Thank you aribeiro for answering my question. I appreciate all answers :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question... but the "simplest" design patterns, that come to mind, based on simple inheritance are [Strategy pattern](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [Template pattern](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method).

Take a look.